# Problems at UK border when visiting for job interview without a visa but no right to work?

Tags: uk, visa-free-entry, working-visas

I am travelling to the UK for a job interview soon and my prospective employer will be reimbursing my expenses. I have a New Zealand passport and have visited the UK several times in the past without incident and without needing a visa. However, I do not have the right to work in the UK. I am worried that I will have trouble at the border, since I am showing an intent to work in the UK. I know the UK is very strict.

What should I do to minimize the chance that I have problems at the UK border when visiting for a job interview without a visa and without a right to work? Am I likely to have problems? Obviously, I would get a work visa if I got the job.

(There are [other questions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26791/which-visa-should-i-get-if-i-am-going-to-uk-for-a-job-interview) about visiting the UK for a job interview, but these do not cover individuals who can travel to the UK without a visa.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are a non-visa national wanting to visit the UK for a job interview.  You are worried (and rightfully so) that you might get some stick at the control point.

The first step is to go to [Appendix 3 of Appendix V](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules) called "Permitted Activities".  See if what you want to do is listed (hint: it is). Make a print out of Appendix 3 with your proposed activities highlighted. Making a print out is not necessary but may increase your comfort.

The next step is to go to the wizard at [Check if you need a UK visa](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa) and follow it through to the last page. There you will find a link to the supporting documents list.

Keep following the links until you arrive at the full [Supporting Documents Guide](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf). Bring as many of those as are relevant to you.

Following these steps you'll be fine and well prepared for your landing interview.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is the correct first link: https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules It says "A visitor may: (a) attend meetings, conferences, seminars, interviews;" That sounds good.