# I have a valid UK Visitor Visa that had main reason as "family visit." May I use this visa for a job interview?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, business-travel

I applied for, and was granted a UK visitor visa (MULT) valid from December 2019 to June 2020. The main reason for the visit was family visit and I used the visa already last Christmas to visit family.

Now, I have an upcoming job interview in the UK and I wonder if I need to obtain a new visa for the job interview or I can use my visit visa for that?

I hold an Egyptian passport and flying from a country in the EU Schengen Area

Comment: Do you mean that "family visit" is printed on the visa?

Comment: No, the visa states "VISIT" in the type section. It states also the default "No work or recourse to public funds" statement

Comment: Otherwise identical question for those who don't require a visa to visit the UK: [Problems at UK border when visiting for job interview without a visa but no right to work?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/93552/3221)

Answer (score 4):

You've received a multiple entry [Standard Visitor Visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa) from the UK.

Regardless of the original reason for the visit, you can use it to enter the UK for any [purpose permitted by this type of visa](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visit-guidance), including tourism, business, or transit. A more detailed list of these permitted activities is in Appendix 3 of the [immigration rules for visitors](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules), where attending an interview is explicitly listed.

You may enter as many times as you wish, but you must depart the UK on or before the expiry date of the visa.

Comment: I'm not so familiar with UK visas, do you mean that this visa can be used for business purposes in the UK (such as being there for a business trip), or that by "business" you mean that the OP can pursue employment in the UK with that visa, even with the "no work" stamp?

Comment: @Upper_Case You can go on a business trip, but you can't work. Appendix 3 of the [visitor rules](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules) shows  specific activities that you can undertake. Attending an interview is explicitly listed.

Comment: @MichaelHampton thank you for the detailed answer. I will keep a printout of the Appendix 3 of the immigration rules for visitors just in case I had issues at the airport